# How to uninstall XAMPP on a Mac?

Tags: php, mysql, macos, xampp

I tried to uninstall and then install again the XAMPP but it keep the information from the previous installation. How can I uninstall and erase all the information? Help

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions should include uninstaller in installation DMG file

---

## Manual uninstall

Delete:

- /Applications/XAMPP
- /Users//.bitnami (hidden folder)

And you can also look to following locations for something like bitnami or xampp:

- /Library/Application Support/ and /Users//Library/Application Support/
- /Library/Preferences/ and /Users//Library/Preferences/

Don't forget to empty bin and kill any remaining processes (like apache2, mysql etc.)